# How to stop auto scrolliing in Flutter listview stream builder?

Tags: android, flutter, listview, dart, stream

When the stream of messages keeps flowing in listview keep scrolling down this disturbs while reading a particular message. Is there a way to avoid autoscrolling while reading some of the already available stream messages?
here is the code which I'm trying to display stream message in listview

```
 List<Comment> comments = <Comment>[];
  StreamSubscription<Comment>? sub;
  Future<void> redditmain() async {
    SharedPreferences preferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();

 
    Reddit reddit = await Reddit.createScriptInstance(
      clientId: cId,
      clientSecret: cSecret,
      userAgent: uAgent,
      username: uname,
      password: upassword, // Fake
    );
   
    sub = reddit.subreddit('cricket').stream.comments().listen((comment) {
      if (comment != null) {
   
        setState(() {
          comments.insert(0, comment);
        });
       
      }
    }) as StreamSubscription<Comment>?;
  }

  @override
  Future<void> didChangeDependencies() async {
    super.didChangeDependencies();
   
    redditmain();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      
        body:Center(
                child: Container(
                  child: Scrollbar(
                    child: ListView.builder(
                      scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                      itemCount: comments.length,
                      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                        if (comments.isNotEmpty) {
                          final Comment comment = comments[index];
                          return Card(
                            elevation: 3,
                            semanticContainer: true,
                            clipBehavior: Clip.antiAliasWithSaveLayer,
                            color: getMyColor(comment
                                    .data!["author_flair_richtext"].isNotEmpty
                                ? comment.data!['author_flair_richtext'][0]['a']
                                : ''),
                            child: ListTile(
                              onTap: () {
                                _launchURL(comment.permalink);
                              },
                              trailing: Text(
                                comment.author,
                                style: TextStyle(color: text_color),
                              ),
                              title: Text(
                                comment.body ?? '',
                                style: TextStyle(color: text_color),
                              ),
                              subtitle: Text(comment.data?['link_title'] ?? '',
                                  style: TextStyle(color: text_color)),
                              leading: Image.network(comment
                                      .data!["author_flair_richtext"].isNotEmpty
                                  ? comment.data!['author_flair_richtext'][0]
                                          ['u'] ??
                                      "https://png.pngtree.com/png-clipart/20190927/ourmid/pngtree-cricket-stumps-and-ball-png-image_1733735.jpg"
                                  : "https://png.pngtree.com/png-clipart/20190927/ourmid/pngtree-cricket-stumps-and-ball-png-image_1733735.jpg"),
                              // Text(comment.data?['author_flair_css_class'] ?? ''),
                            ),
                          );
                        } else
                          return Theme(
                            data: Theme.of(context)
                                .copyWith(accentColor: Colors.red),
                            child: new CircularProgressIndicator(),
                          );
                      },
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ));
  }
```

this makes the stream flowing continuously at a higher rate so when I scroll down to read the particular message it kept moving as a new stream message comes in.
I want to read the message without getting scrolled down the page from incoming streams is there a way to achieve this? Any suggestion on this will be very helpful, will be looking forward to your solutions.

**Edit** I tried the solution as given by @downgrade and updated my code as below. Initially, it loads a stream of messages and displays scrolled to the bottom of the screen. as I scroll to the top all listview turns into a circular indicator as shown in this [image: pic]

```
List<Comment> comments = <Comment>[];
  StreamSubscription<Comment>? sub;
  late StreamQueue<Comment?> commentQueue;
  static const int commentLimit = 100;
  Future<void> redditmain() async {



    Reddit reddit = await Reddit.createScriptInstance(
      clientId: cId,
      clientSecret: cSecret,
      userAgent: uAgent,
      username: uname,
      password: upassword, // Fake
    );
    setState(() {
      commentQueue = StreamQueue<Comment?>(
          reddit.subreddit('cricket').stream.comments(limit: commentLimit));
    });


  }

  @override
  Future<void> didChangeDependencies() async {
    super.didChangeDependencies();
    // getEmail();
    redditmain();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
     
      body: cId == null
          ? Container(
              color: Colors.transparent,
              child: Center(
                child: CircularProgressIndicator(
                  valueColor:
                      AlwaysStoppedAnimation<Color>(Colors.deepPurpleAccent),
                ),
              ),
            )
          : Center(
              child: Container(
                child: Scrollbar(
                  child: ListView.builder(
                    reverse: true,
                    scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                    itemCount: commentLimit,
                    itemBuilder: (context, index) => FutureBuilder<Comment?>(
                      future: commentQueue.next,
                      builder:
                          (BuildContext ctx, AsyncSnapshot<Comment?> snap) {
                        final Comment? comment = snap.data;
                        if (comment == null) {
                          return Card(
                            elevation: 3,
                            semanticContainer: true,
                            clipBehavior: Clip.antiAliasWithSaveLayer,
                            child: ListTile(
                              title: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                            ),
                          );
                        }
                        return Card(
                          elevation: 3,
                          // color: (index % 2 == 0) ? Colors.yellow : Colors.white,
                          semanticContainer: true,
                          clipBehavior: Clip.antiAliasWithSaveLayer,
                          // child:Image.network('https://placeimg.com/640/480/any',fit:BoxFit.fill),
                          color: getMyColor(comment!
                                  .data!["author_flair_richtext"].isNotEmpty
                              ? comment!.data!['author_flair_richtext'][0]['a']
                              : ''),
                          child: ListTile(
                            onTap: () {
                              _launchURL(comment.permalink);
                            },
                            trailing: Text(
                              comment.author,
                              style: TextStyle(color: text_color),
                            ),
                            title: Text(
                              comment.body ?? '',
                              style: TextStyle(color: text_color),
                            ),
                            subtitle: Text(comment.data?['link_title'] ?? '',
                                style: TextStyle(color: text_color)),
                            leading: Image.network(comment
                                    .data!["author_flair_richtext"].isNotEmpty
                                ? comment.data!['author_flair_richtext'][0]
                                        ['u'] ??
                                    "https://png.pngtree.com/png-clipart/20190927/ourmid/pngtree-cricket-stumps-and-ball-png-image_1733735.jpg"
                                : "https://png.pngtree.com/png-clipart/20190927/ourmid/pngtree-cricket-stumps-and-ball-png-image_1733735.jpg"),
                            // Text(comment.data?['author_flair_css_class'] ?? ''),
                          ),
                        );
                      },
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
             );
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT:** I misunderstood the question. It appears OP wants to have a reverse-oriented list that fetches the next comment in the queue when the list edge is reached. Here is a possible way to do that by using the async package:

```
late StreamQueue<Comment?> commentQueue;
static const int commentLimit = 100;

Future<void> redditmain() async {
  Reddit reddit = await Reddit.createScriptInstance(
    clientId: cId,
    clientSecret: cSecret,
    userAgent: uAgent,
    username: uname,
    password: upassword, // Fake
  );

  commentQueue = StreamQueue<Comment?>(
      reddit.subreddit('cricket').stream.comments(limit: commentLimit));
}

@override
Future<void> didChangeDependencies() async {
  super.didChangeDependencies();

  redditmain();
}

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
    child: Container(
      child: Scrollbar(
        child: ListView.builder(
          reverse: true,
          scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
          itemCount: commentLimit,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) => FutureBuilder<Comment?>(
              future: commentQueue.next,
              builder: (BuildContext ctx, AsyncSnapshot<Comment?> snap) {
                final Comment? comment = snap.data;
                if (comment == null) {
                  return ListTile(
                    title: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                  );
                }
                return ListTile(
                  title: Text(comment.body ?? ''),
                );
              }),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ));
}
```

This makes use of the async package's StreamQueue to convert the stream from push to pull behavior via the next() method. We then pass next() to a future builder within the ListView.builder.

Additionally, rather than building a list in reverse and then building a listview from it, we use the reverse optional flag on the ListView to tell it to use a reversed scroll controller.

Note that some ways to improve this could include a check to StreamQueue's hasNext() method in order to prevent trying to fetch another comment when there are none left. Currently, if you exhaust the comment list or exceed 100 comments, you will likely end up with a list tile showing a circular progress indicator indefinitely.

The UI for the loading state can also be improved. This example should simply serve as a proof of concept for pulling stream events when needed rather than waiting for them to push.

**Original Answer**

In order to delay a stream, you can use the pause() method. The most direct answer to your question would be to modify your .listen callback like so:

```
if (comment != null) {
  setState(() {
    comments.insert(0, comment);
  });
  
  // Delay next item for one second
  sub.pause(Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 1))); 
}
```

However, you likely will want to load a certain number of comments immediately and then delay after that first batch is displayed:

```
List<Comment> comments = <Comment>[];
StreamSubscription<Comment>? sub;
var firstBatch = 10; // How many comments should we load first?

Future<void> redditmain() async {
  Reddit reddit = await Reddit.createScriptInstance(
    clientId: cId,
    clientSecret: cSecret,
    userAgent: uAgent,
    username: uname,
    password: upassword, // Fake
  );

  sub = reddit.subreddit('cricket').stream.comments().listen((comment) {
    if (comment != null) {
      setState(() {
        comments.insert(0, comment);
      });
      if (firstBatch == 0) {
        // First load is done, delay all remaining
        sub.pause(Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 1)));
      } else {
        // First load is pending, decrement counter
        firstBatch--;
      }
    }
  }) as StreamSubscription<Comment>?;
}
```

This will load 10 comments as soon as the screen inits and the stream is available, all comments after that will load one per second.

Answer (score 0):

Using just `ListView` will work, adding `ListView.builder` will make it scrollable, as `ListView.builder` is used for dynamic lists.

Comment: I tried changing to listview only but it doesn't have all the properties like itemcount ,itembuilder which are necessary do display stream messages